# How to communicate between 2 scenes in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I would like to make a color system for my player. In my game scene the player can pick up the coins and the amount of coins will be save with playerprefs , but I don' know how can I use the amount of coins in my menu scene. 
And I need some help to a player color selecter too. When the player select a color than in my game scene must instiate the player with the color.
Soo I think , i need to know how to communicate between 2 scenes.
Can somebody help me with some tutorial?

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, which I feel comes down to a matter of taste: save data to file, use DoNotDestroyOnLoad...

But from what I understand, the recommended way now is to create a "manager scene" which will stay alive throughout the lifetime of your app and pass data to and from your other scenes as they are opened and closed, instead of using DontDestroyOnLoad:

> It is recommended to avoid using DontDestroyOnLoad to persist manager GameObjects that you want to survive across scene loads. Instead, create a manager scene that has all your managers and use SceneManager.LoadScene(, LoadSceneMode.Additive) and SceneManager.UnloadScene to manage your game progress. [src](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html)

See the Unity guide [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html). Basically you would have 2 scenes open at the same time, at any given moment: the manager scene and whatever the actual active game scene is. Then you can communicate between scripts in the two open scenes via event delegates. The way it would work is:

1. Player selects color in scene1
2. Color is sent from scene1 to manager scene via event delegate
3. scene1 is unloaded and scene2 is loaded
4. Color is sent from manager scene to scene2

This is the approach I've been using for a project now which looks like this: 
[image]

"0-Attract", "1-Sealant", "2-Paint", and "3-Conclusion" are my actual game scenes, and "Manager Scene" contains everything that exists in every other scene (thus no reason to kill and respawn them) as well as all of my "manager" scripts which handle the passing of data between scenes.

Note that multi-scene editing can be confusing at first, as there are new things you need to pay attention to (i.e., which scene is currently "active" and what that means) so be sure to go through the unity guide I posed above. Good luck!

Comment: Thank You! I'll see it

Answer (score 0):

you can Call DontDestroyOnLoad method on any object that you want that will remain wen you are moving the a new scene so it will not be destroyed when scene is closing.

Comment: And , when I restart the game do I have the color what I selected or do I have to select again?

Comment: You should save the setting (Using PlayerPrefs) for loading it after exiting.